# Automatically resize text widget's width to fit all text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am attempting to print out tables using the Text widget. I have created a method for doing this by using labels and frames, but the problem is that I will need to present larger tables to the point where I will need to use a scroll bar.

I am using tabs to make a table for the text widget, and it works well, but I can't seem to figure out a way to set the width of the widget to fit the text. I'm attempting to do it with the get_width() method below, but it doesn't always work.

The width option is measured in average sized characters for the font, but the problem is that the size of a tab 'character' varies. The way the tab key works for the text widget is different than the print() functions for a terminal or text file.

Here is my code below:

```
from tkinter import *
import math


class App(Text):
    def __init__(self, matrix, parent, **kwargs):
        Text.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.matrix = matrix

        temp = []
        for row in matrix:
            temp.append(len(row))

        # Making sure all the rows are of equal length and string values...
        for row in matrix:
            for _ in range(max(temp) - len(row)):
                row.append('')

        matrix = [[str(matrix[r][c]) for c in range(len(matrix[0]))] for r in range(len(matrix))]
        
        # I need to get the maximum length for each column in the matrix...
        c_lengths = {}
        for c in range(len(matrix[0])):
            c_lengths.update({c: []})
            for r in range(len(matrix)):
                c_lengths[c].append(len(matrix[r][c]))

        self.tab_list = []
        for r in range(len(matrix)):
            temp = []
            for c in range(len(matrix[0])):
                if c != len(matrix[0]) - 1:
                    tab_count = (math.floor(max(c_lengths[c])/8)+1)
                    '''if (tab_count + max(c_lengths[c])) % 8 == 0:
                        tab_count += 1'''
                    temp.append(tab_count)
                    tabs = ['\t'] * tab_count
                    string = matrix[r][c] + ''.join(tabs)
                else:
                    string = matrix[r][c]
                self.insert(END, string)
            self.tab_list.append(sum(temp))
            self.insert(END, '\n')

        self.configure(state=DISABLED, wrap=NONE, width=self.get_width())

    def get_width(self):
        temp = []
        for row in self.matrix:
            temp.append(len(''.join(row)))
        return max(temp) + max(self.tab_list)*4


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import random
    root = Tk()
    root.state('zoomed')

    m = [['0' for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(40)]

    for i in range(40):
        for j in range(5):
            m[i][j] = '*' * random.randint(1, 25)

    App(m, root, font=('Times', '12'), height=40).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Here is the output:
[image]

This run worked out good, but sometimes it cuts off some of the table.

Comment: your question is not clear. Do you want the Text widget to be scrollable?

Comment: @JacksonPro I want the widget to autofit the width to fit the text inside. The get_width() method that I have above doesn't always work because it depends on the length of the tab character which varies.

Comment: I'll give you an answer would you mind checking that? might not be 100% correct.

Comment: Yes I can check your answer @JacksonPro

Comment: Does my answer work for all the cases?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```py
from tkinter import *
import math


class App(Text):
    def __init__(self, matrix, parent, **kwargs):
        Text.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.matrix = matrix

        temp = []
        for row in matrix:
            temp.append(len(row))

        # Making sure all the rows are of equal length and string values...
        for row in matrix:
            for _ in range(max(temp) - len(row)):
                row.append('')

        matrix = [[str(matrix[r][c]) for c in range(len(matrix[0]))] for r in range(len(matrix))]

        # I need to get the maximum length for each column in the matrix...
        c_lengths = {}
        for c in range(len(matrix[0])):
            c_lengths.update({c: []})
            for r in range(len(matrix)):
                c_lengths[c].append(len(matrix[r][c]))

        self.tab_list = []

        for r in range(len(matrix)):
            temp = []
            for c in range(len(matrix[0])):
                if c != len(matrix[0]) - 1:
                    tab_count = (math.floor(max(c_lengths[c])/8)+1)
                    '''if (tab_count + max(c_lengths[c])) % 8 == 0:
                        tab_count += 1'''
                    temp.append(tab_count)
                    tabs = ['\t'] * tab_count
                    string = matrix[r][c] + ''.join(tabs)
                else:
                    string = matrix[r][c]
                self.insert(END, string)
            self.tab_list.append(sum(temp))
            self.insert(END, '\n')

        self.configure(state=DISABLED, wrap=NONE, width=self.getWidth())


    def getWidth(self):
        lst = []

        for x in range(int(self.index('end-1c').split('.')[0])):
            lst.append(len(self.get(f'end-{x} lines linestart', f'end-{x} lines lineend')))

        return max(lst)+52


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import random
    root = Tk()
    root.state('zoomed')

    m = [['0' for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(40)]

    for i in range(40):
        for j in range(5):
            m[i][j] = '*' * random.randint(1, 25)

    App(m, root, font=('Times', '12'), height=40).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Explaination:
`self.get(f'end-{x} lines linestart', f'end-{x} lines lineend')` here `get(index1, index2)` method is used to get characters between index1 and index2.

You can read what `linestart` and `lineend` parameter does [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-index.html)

`end-x` x goes from 0 to the last line, so end-1 is the last before line and so on. So all `end-{x} lines linestart` gets the starting index of each line and `end-{x} lines lineend` get the last index of the same line.

**update**:

Op your get_width:

```
 def get_width(self):
        temp = []
        for row in self.matrix:
            temp.append(len(''.join(row)))
        return max(temp) + max(self.tab_list)*4
```

is the same as

```
    def getWidth(self):
        lst = []
        spaces = []
        for x in range(int(self.index('end-1c').split('.')[0])+1):
            spaces = len([x for x in self.get(f'end-{x} lines linestart', f'end-{x} lines lineend') if x=='\t'])
            lst.append(len(self.get(f'end-{x} lines linestart', f'end-{x} lines lineend'))+spaces*4)
        return max(lst)
```

not much difference.

I also found out that the tabs are inconsistent I am not entirely sure of the reason. Setting `self['tabs'] = '2c'` gives more consistency you might want to check out more it [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-tabs.html)

Comment: OP if this is what you were looking for hit the tick mark and I'll add an explanation. If you have any queries, comment.

Comment: This works better than what I had for sure, but there's still some extra space for the width. But I'm happy as long as it shows everything horizontally. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @GabeMorris you can change that extra width by changing `return max(lst)+52` <- this factor

Comment: Would be better if you could add more details so others might find this more helpful.

Comment: @CoolCloud yes I will, I just am checking if there is a  better way of doing this.